# Accessing List Custom Settings in JavaScript custom button

Tags: javascript, custom-button, customsetting

Basically this question is answered in many blogs but none of them serves my purpose. I can see contradictory statements as well, whether or not a List Custom setting be accessed from a custom button using JS.
Here is my JS of the custom button:-

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/apex.js")} 
var userProfile = "{!$Profile.Name}";
var query1 = "SELECT Id,Tax_Exempt__c,FEIN__c,Tax_Exempt_Expiration_Date__c from Account WHERE Id='{!Opportunity.AccountId}'"; 
var rec1 = sforce.connection.query(query1); 
var rec2 = rec1.getArray('records'); 
var taxExempt=rec2[0].Tax_Exempt__c;
var fein=rec2[0].FEIN__c;
var oppStage = "{!Opportunity.StageName}"; 
var user = {!ISPICKVAL( $User.UserType , 'PowerPartner')}
var RollSync = "{!Opportunity.Roll_Up_Sync_Quote__c}"; 
var customersigner = "{!Opportunity.Customer_Signed_by_Contact__c}"; 
var installcontact = "{!Opportunity.Install_Contact__c}";
var lines;
var loaReq = false;
var query2 = "SELECT SyncedQuoteId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id='{!Opportunity.Id}'"; 
var rec3 = sforce.connection.query(query2); 
var rec4 = rec3.getArray('records'); 
/*var query3 = "SELECT Service_Type__c FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId ='{!Opportunity.Id}' AND Service_Type__c = 'Business Trunking'"; 
var rec5 = sforce.connection.query(query3); 
var rec6 = rec5.getArray('records');*/
var query4 = "SELECT Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}' AND (Service_Type__c = 'Hosted Voice' OR Service_Type__c = 'Business Phone')"; 
var rec7 = sforce.connection.query(query4); 
var rec8 = rec7.getArray('records'); 
var query5 = "SELECT Id FROM Telephone_Number_Information__c WHERE Opportunity__c ='{!Opportunity.Id}'"; 
var rec9 = sforce.connection.query(query5); 
var rec10 = rec9.getArray('records'); 
var query6 = "SELECT lines__c FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}' AND IsSyncing = true";
var rec11 = sforce.connection.query(query6);
var rec12 = rec11.getArray('records');
var query7 = "SELECT Service_Type__c FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId ='{!Opportunity.Id}' AND Service_Type__c = 'Enterprise Trunking'"; 
var rec13 = sforce.connection.query(query7); 
var rec14 = rec13.getArray('records'); 
var query8 = "Select id, PricebookEntryId, PricebookEntry.Product2Id from OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId ='{!Opportunity.Id}'";
var rec15 = sforce.connection.query(query8);
var rec16 = rec15.getArray('records');
var query9 = "Select Product_Id__c from Product_List__c"
var rec17 = sforce.connection.query(query9);
var rec18 = rec17.getArray('records');
alert(rec18);
for (var i=0;i<rec16.length;i++)
{
    for (var j=0;j=rec18.length;j++)
    {
        if(rec16.records[i].PricebookEntry.Product2Id == rec18.records[j].Product_Id__c)
            loaReq = true;
    }
}
var OpportunityObj = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity"); 
OpportunityObj.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}';
var updateOpty = 'false';
if(rec12.length>0)
{
    lines = rec12[0].lines__c;
}
else{
    lines=0;
}


if(taxExempt == '' || taxExempt == null) 
{ 
    alert('Tax Exempt is mandatory on Account in order to generate Service Agreement'); 
} 
if(fein == '' || fein == null) 
{ 
    alert('Federal Tax ID Number is mandatory on Account in order to generate Service Agreement'); 
} 
else if(oppStage == 'New Opportunity') 
{ 
    alert('Sorry! You cannot create Service Agreement when Stage is "New Opportunity"'); 
} 
else if(RollSync == 0) 
{ 
    alert('Please Sync atleast one Quote'); 
}
else if(customersigner == "") 
{ 
    alert('Customer Signer should not be empty'); 
} 
else if(installcontact == "") 
{ 
    alert('Install Contact should not be empty'); 
} 
else if(rec8.length>0 && rec10.length == 0) 
{ 
    alert('Telephone Number is required when Voice Products are included'); 
}
else if((rec8.length>0 && rec10.length != lines) && lines != 0 && lines!=null) 
{ 
    alert('No of TNs records must be the sum of Full Featured Lines Products ,Basic Lines Products,Toll Free Number BP Products and Remote Call Forwarding BP Products.'); 
}
/*else if(rec6.length>0 && user==true) 
{ 
alert('Please contact CSS or Channel Manager to proceed with the order.'); 
}*/
else if(rec10.length > 0 && lines == 0)
{
    alert('Telephone Number not needed');
} 
else if(userProfile == "Senior Partner Community")
{ 
    OpportunityObj.Stage_Flag__c= 'True';
    OpportunityObj.Service_Agreement_Status__c = 'In Process';
    updateOpty = 'True'
}
else if(userProfile == "Channel CSS" || userProfile == "Sales - Alt Channels" || userProfile == "Manager of Channel Sales")
{
    OpportunityObj.StageName="Forecasted to Close this FP";
    OpportunityObj.Service_Agreement_Status__c = 'In Process';
    updateOpty = 'True';
}
if(updateOpty == 'True')
{
    result = sforce.connection.update([OpportunityObj]);
    if (result[0].getBoolean("success"))
    {
        if(loaReq == false)
        {
            location.reload(); 

            window.open("https://composer.congamerge.com?sessionId={!API.Session_ID}&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_290}&id={!Opportunity.Id}&TemplateId=a0r54000000696x&LG3=1&LGAttachOption=0&AttachmentParentId={!Opportunity.Id}&DefaultPDF=1&SC0=1&FP0=1&QueryId=[TelephoneNumber]a0q54000000HDiq,[FFBusinessPhone]a0q54000000HDiw,[TelephoneNumberFF]a0q54000000HDj3,[BSCBusinessPhone]a0q54000000HDix,[TelephoneNumberBSC]a0q54000000HDir,[TFBusinessPhone]a0q54000000HDj2,[TelephoneNumberTF]a0q54000000HDj2,[RCFBusinessPhone]a0q54000000HDj1,[TelephoneNumberRCF]a0q54000000HDj5,[AllBusinessPhone]a0q54000000HDj0,[Internet]a0q54000000HDiq,[Video]a0q54000000HDiu,[Phone]a0q54000000HDiv,[BTrunking]a0q54000000HDip,[ETrunking]a0q54000000HDio&FlattenPDFForms=1&DS7=1",'_blank','location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
        }
        else
        {
            location.reload(); 

            window.open("https://composer.congamerge.com?sessionId={!API.Session_ID}&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_290}&id={!Opportunity.Id}&TemplateId=a0r54000000696x,a0r540000006mvH&LG3=1&LGAttachOption=0&AttachmentParentId={!Opportunity.Id}&DefaultPDF=1&SC0=1&FP0=1&QueryId=[TelephoneNumber]a0q54000000HDiq,[FFBusinessPhone]a0q54000000HDiw,[TelephoneNumberFF]a0q54000000HDj3,[BSCBusinessPhone]a0q54000000HDix,[TelephoneNumberBSC]a0q54000000HDir,[TFBusinessPhone]a0q54000000HDj2,[TelephoneNumberTF]a0q54000000HDj2,[RCFBusinessPhone]a0q54000000HDj1,[TelephoneNumberRCF]a0q54000000HDj5,[AllBusinessPhone]a0q54000000HDj0,[Internet]a0q54000000HDiq,[Video]a0q54000000HDiu,[Phone]a0q54000000HDiv,[BTrunking]a0q54000000HDip,[ETrunking]a0q54000000HDio&FlattenPDFForms=1&DS7=1",'_blank','location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        alert("Failed to update Opportunity" + result[0]);
    }
}
```

The alert(rec18) is giving this output:-

```
cs4O.salesforce.com says:
{type:Product_List_c, Id:nuII,
Product_Id__c:'O1ti00000057dNnAAI',}
```

And is immediately followed by this error:-

```
cs4O.salesforce.com says:
A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or
link was encountered:
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

What is wrong? The alert clearly shows that I'm able to get the values of the Custom Setting. Then whats the error about?

Comment: It doesn't look like `rec18` is the source of your error being that you're not referencing a property of `0` on `rec18`. What is `rec16`? I'm assuming `rec16.records` is undefined

Comment: Apologies for the typo. it should be j=0. btw, its still giving the same error. rec16 is the collection of records from query8, and it is not null.

Comment: Gotcha, although the error being thrown indicates that `rec18.records` would be undefined. Try to alert that instead to narrow down the source of the error.

Comment: I've put alert for rec16 and rec18 both. Below are the results:-

rec16:-

{type:OpportunityLineltem, Id:'00k540000039I6tAAE',
PricebookEntryld:'01ui000000FkEs6AAF', PricebookEntry:
{type: 'PricebookEntry', Id:nuII,
Product2ld :'01ti00000057d NnAAI', ), },
{type:'OpportunityLineltem', Id:'00k540000039I6sAAE',
PricebookEntryld:'01ui000000MgpxuAAB', PricebookEntry:
{type: 'PricebookEntry', Id:nuII,
Product2ld:'01ti0000005HG2dAAG', ), }

rec18:-

{type:Product_List_c, Id:nuII,
Product_Id__c:'O1ti00000057dNnAAI',}
The alert for their corresponding length gave 2 and 1 respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the property `records` is undefined.

```
var query8 = "Select id, PricebookEntryId, PricebookEntry.Product2Id from OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId ='{!Opportunity.Id}'";
var rec15 = sforce.connection.query(query8);
var rec16 = rec15.getArray('records');
var query9 = "Select Product_Id__c from Product_List__c"
var rec17 = sforce.connection.query(query9);
var rec18 = rec17.getArray('records');
```

While `rec18` and `rec16` may not be `undefined`, as demonstrated by your alert, they do not appear to have a property called `records`(atleast `rec18` doesn't).

Earlier in your code, you instantiate `rec12` in the same manner:

```
var query6 = "SELECT lines__c FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}' AND IsSyncing = true";
var rec11 = sforce.connection.query(query6);
var rec12 = rec11.getArray('records');
```

And then reference it in this manner:

```
if(rec12.length>0)
{
    lines = rec12[0].lines__c;
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, changing your nested for loop like such:

```
for (var i=0;i<rec16.length;i++)
{
    for (var j=0;j<rec18.length;j++)
    {
        if(rec16[i].PricebookEntry.Product2Id == rec18[j].Product_Id__c)
            loaReq = true;
    }
}
```

should solve your issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My bad. Advice worked like a charm. Along with the reference, I had to change the nested for loop's syntax as well like this:-
for (var j=0;j<rec18.length;j++)
Thanks a ton.

Comment: @AbhijeetMitra No problem, glad I could help